numpy numbers output with type cast around them, which is a bug in my program
I am casting a python tuple to a numpy array, using a quaternion function, and then casting the returning numpy array back to a tuple. Here, start_pos is a tuple (0,0,0). The second tuple goes into a list.
current_pos = np.array(start_pos)
current_quaternion = Quaternion.from_axis_angle(np.array([0,0,1]), math.radians(rotation))
vertices.append(tuple(current_pos))

This used to work on my last laptop, but now, when I run my source code the output of tuple(current_pos) looks like (np.int64(0), np.int64(0), np.int64(0))
This doesn't work for me because vertices needs to be written to a file, and the format needs raw numbers like 0.4999238475781956, not np.float64(0.4999238475781956).
Previously, the same source code output the correct thing after tuple(current_pos). It output raw numbers. When I imported my files into the new laptop and installed python and numpy, something changed to cause this issue.

Python version: 3.12.4 (tags/v3.12.4:8e8a4ba, Jun  6 2024, 19:30:16) [MSC v.1940 64 bit (AMD64)]
NumPy version: 2.0.1

with start_pos = (0,0,0), I expected a tuple of 3 raw numbers, as floats, to be appended to a list vertices. Instead, vertices looks like:
[(np.int64(0), np.int64(0), np.int64(0)),
 (np.float64(0.0), np.float64(0.0), np.float64(1.0)),
 (np.float64(0.4999238475781956), np.float64(0.008726203218641754), np.float64(1.8660254037844388)),
 (np.float64(0.0), np.float64(0.0), np.float64(2.0))]


Can you please state from which package you are importing Quaternion?  (I´ve tried at least two iplementations and none had .from_axis_angle)

Also,  if you can paste some snippet of how are you writting these numbers to your desired file - I feel like a tweak at that point could fix the issue for you. I just checked. Numpy scalars are in most ways compliant and interchangeable with numbers. It is just their default representation as strings which have changed for numpy 2.0

Do these answer your question? How to stop numpy floats being displayed as "np.float64"?, How to print a list of numpy.float32 values?

What does the quaternion function have to do with the problem? In this snippet, the result is unused and it doesn't even take current_pos as a parameter.

Have you considered using .tolist()? It returns Python scalars instead of NumPy scalars. Also, to be clear, you've always been getting NumPy scalars, they just looked like Python scalars before.

How are you writing these tuples to a file?

I'm guessing the difference is that you were originally on Numpy 1.2x and updated to numpy 2.0. As per the release notes, there has been a change to how floats are now represented. The release notes mention this may be an issue when outputting to a file. You don't show how you are printing to a file and haven't explained why you are using tuples rather than a 2D array, so my suggestions will be limited.
If you want to keep your current code, convert the numpy array to a Python list of floats when creating your tuple.
vertices.append(tuple(current_pos.tolist()))

Or, you can downgrade numpy to 1.2x or do what the documentation says for using the legacy representation, i.e. add np.set_printoptions(legacy="1.25") after your imports.

Maybe just tuple(current_pos.tolist())

@juanpa.arrivillaga Good point, I overcomplicated it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Thank you very much, this gives me numerous ways to fix it. I learned an important lesson about checking release notes.

import numpy as np
import math
from some_quaternion_library import Quaternion  

vertices = []
start_pos = (0, 0, 0)
rotation = 30  

current_pos = np.array(start_pos)
current_quaternion = Quaternion.from_axis_angle(np.array([0, 0, 1]), math.radians(rotation))

# Convert NumPy array elements to native Python types
def convert_to_native_types(array):
    return tuple(array.astype(float) if array.dtype.kind == 'f' else array.astype(int))

vertices.append(convert_to_native_types(current_pos))

quaternion_array = current_quaternion.to_numpy()  
vertices.append(convert_to_native_types(quaternion_array))

print(vertices)


While this code may solve the problem, adding a description of how would help a lot. You can [edit]. For tips and other pointers, see [answer].

Why not just use .tolist() to convert to native Python types?
